# Tags with limited use: no one with enough rep to edit?

Tags: discussion, reputation, tags, tag-wiki

Some tags on the Stack Exchange network, such as the `Zune`or `Zune-software` tags, are not used much, which results in a number of users who may be active in that tag, but do not have enough reputation to edit those tags...In order to edit the `Zune-software` tag on Super User, for example, I need 1500 rep (check), have 100 or more rep in that tag (nope) and/or be in the top 20 *answerers* of that tag (nope).  However, I know quite a bit about the Zune software, and could write a tag-wiki about that tag, but I do not have enough rep (in the specific tag) to create a tag-wiki, which means that it will probably never get created, because that tag will not grow enough, and there won't be users with enough rep to create?

> The point: How will tag-wikis of
>   limited-use tags get created?

What's your take?

Comment: My take is that tags with few active users will not need a tag wiki since there is there is little use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO tag-wikis are mostly a dupe of wikipedia. There are some advantageous of having it on SO, but I suspect very few people typing "C#" into a a search engine to get some general info on it would go to a stackoverflow tag wiki before wikipedia, if they can even find it.

If a tag is not used very much, then few people will be looking at the wiki anyway. We could spend time making a good wiki-page for the [brainf*** tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck), but as it has a very small community, very few will actually see it, and they'll hopefully go to wikipedia where they can find all the info they need (and edit in links to helpful SO questions...;) You can always ask on meta for a wiki to be edited if you really feel their is a need.

Bottom line is that the creators didn't decide this was worth the extra complexity. :D

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer relevant; anyone can propose a tag wiki edit through the "Improve description" link and the tag wiki edit will go into the edit queue where users who can edit the tag can approve the edit.